# Dompdf returns an empty pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I have a problem with dompdf when creating a new pdf from html.

No matter what html code I pass to it, it always returns a blank pdf with no content.

I have no warnings or fatal errors in the log.

Any idea what it could be ?
Install the library with composer

Here goes my code:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
        
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4');

        $dompdf->loadHtml('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head><body><p>ALOHA</p></body></html>');
        
        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $dompdf->stream($nombre_pdf, array('compress'=>1,'attachment'=>1));
```

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works perfectly, showing "ALOHA" in the body of the downloaded PDF

Comment: This means that you have an error in your configuration. Add the most verbose ini_set for errors. Try surrounding with a try/catch and echo the generic exception message. Double check your Dompdf installation.

Comment: Thanks @AndreaOlivato I was trying what you told me but I can't get the script to return any error or warning. I'll keep trying, thanks again!